# Change Python Tooltip 'Body' Text Color?

Tags: accessibility

[image: Not enough contrast in Python tooltip text]

I'd like to increase the contrast between the tooltip background and the Python text. Available presets don't seem to change the text color, just the background. In Preferences > Theme > User Interface > Tooltip, there is no color swatch for this.

Screenshot: I have to squint to see either the gray text on yellow or gray on black.

How do I go about either controlling the text color or increasing the contrast between it and the background?

Comment: Hi. I did remove the 'text' tag for a reason. I really don't think we need a tag like that on the site. If you would like to suggest and discuss why this new tag is needed you can do so [here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/). The 'visibility' tag also doesn't seem related to this. The 'customization' tag is used for questions about customising blender, which is what your question is about, so I would suggest leaving it. Having the wrong tags may result in your question not being found by people who can answer it. Thanks.

Comment: I see your point, but this post isn't about cosmetic changes or making changes simply because I have different taste than those who supplied Blender's themes. The issue is text visibility for those with poor eyesight (like me) and that's why I chose the tags I did. The tags you picked don't reflect the reasoning behind my question.
Also, I followed that link to where you say I can discuss this, but that's just telling me to defend how I framed the question and brings me no closer to an answer.

Comment: Hi. You want to change the default way blender looks. That is customisation. It doesn't matter what your motivation is. You could argue that the visibility tag could be used here as it unfortunately lacks a definition or usage guideline but it is generally used for the visibility of objects. The meta is a place where you can discuss this site, which includes asking a question which suggests a new tag (if you really feel that the 'text' tag is needed). All I can say is that as a regular user of this site I believe these are the correct tags. Thanks.

Comment: That only leaves why you're bothering to get involved with this question. You obviously don't know the answer. From your comments, you don't understand the problem, either. You aren't a moderator, and finally, I'm not finding your involvement at all helpful. So, how about you let me use the tags I feel are appropriate and go find something else to do?

Comment: All I can repeat is that having the wrong tags may impact who finds and answers this question, and again, repeat that the meta site is available to suggest tags or discuss this site.

Comment: @no-one Ray has been on this site quite longer than you, has been a tireless maintainer of our tag system and knows them quite well. The tags you have assigned to you question generally have a different meaning than what you interpreted. [Text] usually refers to 3D Text objects in a scene, and [Visibility] usually related to 3D viewport object visibility/renderability, so his tags are actually more helpful to your question than harmful.

Comment: Then perhaps one of you can tell me which tags I would use to mean 'change the visibility of text.' Being visually-impaired, I'm simply looking for a way to talk about that. FYI, when I first typed one of those tags—either 'text' or 'visilbity,' I don't remember which—I was presented with a dialog asking if I wanted to create a new tag. And if you go to the Tags page on this site and type, 'text,' it doesn't come up and that makes me wonder how that tag could generally mean what you say it means when the tag system implies it's never before been used.

Comment: My bad, will look into it.

Comment: @Robert: If you look at the screenshot, you'll see there are two distinctly different treatments for the text in a tooltip. None of the preference settings I've been able to find will affect the Python code written in the lower part of the pop-up. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The tinting is hard coded in `interface_region_tooltip.c` with the line `rgb_tint(python_color, 0.0f, 0.0f, tone_bg, 0.5f); /* dark gray  */`. The way it's currently implemented you would have to compiler Blender yourself to change this.

Comment: @RobertGützkow: I suspected as much. Thanks. You've been very helpful. I have compiled Blender in the past, so I'll take a stab at rolling my own solution.